# Auto return from paypal to my site not working in codeigniter using sandbox

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am stuck in using this form submission to go on [[image]paypal](/questions/tagged/paypal) sandbox and want auto redirect to my function.

I have set the auto return URL from pay merchant account
I have set auto return to my method that is `http//:mysite/mycontorller/myfunction`. from account management page but it still doesn't redirect from the paypal page.

My code:

```
<form method="post" name="form<?php echo $plan_data['price_plan_id']; ?>" id="payment" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>">
                   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
                        <input type='hidden' name='business' id="business" value='<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Price Plan'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='<?php echo $plan_data['price_plan_id']; ?>'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='<?php echo $plan_data['total_price']; ?>'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
                        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
                      <input type="hidden" name="TOKEN" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                        <!--<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://192.168.1.189/mingout_development/v1/success'>-->
                        <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='<?php echo base_url(); ?>pricing/cancel/<?php echo $user_id; ?>'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='return' value='<?php echo base_url(); ?>pricing/success/<?php echo $user_id; ?>'>
                        <!--<input type='hidden' name='rm' value='1'>-->
                        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pricing/test/<?php echo $user_id; ?>" />
                  </form>
```

And this the method for auto redirection

```
function test(){
  print_r($_POST);
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have got the solution i have used this library and bingooooo
http://ci-merchant.org/